# I do not know the point at which this Taylor series was derived, can someone explain please?

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

I am required to derive Euler's method through Taylor's Theorem. I have been given the Taylor series for $y(t)$ as shown below. However I do not understand what point the Taylor series was derived. Isit at the point $a=t_i$ or $a=t_{i+1}?$

In this case, $y(t)$ is a unique solution to

$$ \frac{dy}{dt} = f(t, y),$$
$$ where \space\space  a ≤ t ≤ b\space and\space\space y(a) = α.$$

The taylor series for this solution is

$$y(t_{i+1}) = y(t_{i}) + (t_{i+1} − t_{i})y′(t_i) + \frac{(t_{i+1} − t_i)^2}{2}y′′(ξ_i)$$

where i = 0, 1, 2, . . . , N − 1 and for some number $ξ_i$ in $(t_i, t_{i+1})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (truncated) series is from the point $t_i$. Note that each of the polynomial terms is of the form $(t-t_i)$, where $t=t_{i+1}$. Additionally, the initial term is $y(t_i)$, so when $t=t_i$, the series evaluates to $y(t_i)$. If it were from $t_{i+1}$, then the initial term would be $y(t_{i+1})$, since that is what $y$ is at $t_{i+1}$.

You might think of it like equations of motion; $x(t)\approx x(t_0)+x'(t_0)(t-t_0)+x''(t_0)\frac{(t-t_0)^2}{2}$. You start, at $t=t_0$, from the position $x(t_0)$. As $t$ grows, $x(t)$ will initially move at its initial velocity, but the velocity will move in the direction of the initial acceleration. Regardless, when $t=t_0$, we are at the starting point, so the first term must be $x(t_0)$.

Comment: Ok, your explanation makes sense. However why was $t_{i+1}$ used instead of $t$ in the equation?

Comment: Also does the symbol $y''(ξ_i)$ mean 'and so on' of the Taylor series?

Comment: @Jed: The value $t_{i+1}$ was used because that is the next value in the sequence. Remember that $(t_{i+1}-t_i)+t_i=t_{i+1}$. You are essentially right in saying that $y''(\xi_i)$ is "and so on," but what's really happening is that $y''(\xi_i)$ is compensating for the truncation; it's really saying that there are other terms behind it.